# How do i convert the contents of a .txt file in linux from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a bash file, do-something.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -efa > /command.txt
sed -i 's/root     //g' command.txt
sed -i '/UID/d' command.txt
sed -i -E 's/.{26}:00:.*//g' command.txt
sed -i '1s/^/kill -9 /' command.txt
sed -e :a -e '{N; s/\n/ /g;ta}' command.txt
```

It currently lists process ids in command.txt in a vertical format, i'd like them to be listed horizontally so i could run the command using "./do-something" and have all processes be killed.

Comment: Have you looked into [process management](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement)? This looks extremely dodgy.

Comment: Please show us actual input and desired output.

Comment: `ps -ea -o pid= | sort -nr | xargs echo` will get you the list of all current PIDs from latest to earliest.

Comment: This script is an excellent example of why `sed -i` is a terrible idea.

Comment: Ignoring the question of whether or not you should parse the output of ps like this, try: `ps -efa | sed -e 's/root     //g' -e '/UID/d' ... > command.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Simply `cat` the file with pids to `xargs | kill -9` like so:

```
cat pids.txt | xargs kill -9
```

Example:

```
echo 12345 67890 | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the kill command with all PID at the end in one line with this command:

```
ps -efa | awk 'BEGIN{printf "kill -9 "}{printf "%s ",$2}'
```